# Parse CSV file and aggregate the values

Tags: python, file

I'd like to parse a CSV file and aggregate the values. The city row has repeating values (sample):

```
CITY,AMOUNT
London,20
Tokyo,45
London,55
New York,25
```

After parsing the result should be something like:

```
CITY, AMOUNT
London,75
Tokyo,45
New York,25
```

I've written the following code to extract the unique city names:

```
def main():
    contrib_data = list(csv.DictReader(open('contributions.csv','rU')))
    combined = []
    for row in contrib_data:
      if row['OFFICE'] not in combined:
        combined.append(row['OFFICE'])
```

How do I then aggregate values?

Comment: HINT: Use a dictionary instead of a list. CITY as key, sum(AMOUNT) as value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested in Python 3.2.2:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv', newline=''))
cities = defaultdict(int)
for row in reader:
    cities[row["CITY"]] += int(row["AMOUNT"])

writer = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'w', newline = ''))
writer.writerow(["CITY", "AMOUNT"])
writer.writerows([city, cities[city]] for city in cities)
```

Result:

```
CITY,AMOUNT
New York,25
London,75
Tokyo,45
```

As for your added requirements:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def default_factory():
    return [0, None, None, 0]

reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv', newline=''))
cities = defaultdict(default_factory)
for row in reader:
    amount = int(row["AMOUNT"])
    cities[row["CITY"]][0] += amount
    max = cities[row["CITY"]][1]
    cities[row["CITY"]][1] = amount if max is None else amount if amount > max else max
    min = cities[row["CITY"]][2]
    cities[row["CITY"]][2] = amount if min is None else amount if amount < min else min
    cities[row["CITY"]][3] += 1
for city in cities:
    cities[city][3] = cities[city][0]/cities[city][3] # calculate mean

writer = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'w', newline = ''))
writer.writerow(["CITY", "AMOUNT", "max", "min", "mean"])
writer.writerows([city] + cities[city] for city in cities)
```

This gives you

```
CITY,AMOUNT,max,min,mean
New York,25,25,25,25.0
London,75,55,20,37.5
Tokyo,45,45,45,45.0
```

Note that under Python 2, you'll need the additional line `from __future__ import division` at the top to get correct results.

Comment: Tested this on Python 2.7 and it works fine. I'm wondering why a regular Dict isn't working, why do I have to use a defaultdict()?

Comment: A `defaultdict(int)` allows you to use keys that aren't defined yet and automatically assigns a value of `0` to them. So you can just do `cities["Bolton"] += 10` and it will either create a new key `"Bolton"` with a value of `10` or add `10` to the value if the key already exists. If you did that with a normal `dict`, you'd get lots of `KeyError`s.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to get MAX, MIN and MEAN values within the same for..loop?

Comment: Kind of. You couldn't use the `defaultdict` the same way then because now you have to store more than just a single integer but an entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict with the value as the AMOUNT might do the trick. Something like the following-

Suppose you read one line at a time and `city` indicates the current city and `amount` indicates the current amount -

```
main_dict = {}

---for loop here---
if city in main_dict:
    main_dict[city] = main_dict[city] + amount
else:
    main_dict[city] = amount
---end for loop---
```

At the end of the loop you will have aggregate values in `main_dict`.

Comment: I keep getting a Key Error when I try it this way.

Comment: Shouldn't be. Can you show the critical part of your code here where you are getting the KeyError.