# Parse CSV file with and aggregate values, multiple columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, aggregate

I would like to adapt the post here ([Parse CSV file and aggregate the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800111/parse-csv-file-and-aggregate-the-values)) to sum multiple columns instead of just one.

So for these data:

```
CITY,AMOUNT,AMOUNT2,AMOUNTn
London,20,21,22
Tokyo,45,46,47
London,55,56,57
New York,25,26,27
```

How can I get this:

```
CITY,AMOUNT,AMOUNT2,AMOUNTn
London,75,77,79
Tokyo,45,46,47
New York,25,26,27
```

I will have several thousand columns eventually, and unfortunately I can not use the pandas package for this task.  Here is the code I have just aggregates all three AMOUNT cols into one, which is not what I am after

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def default_factory():
    return [0, None, None, 0]

reader = csv.DictReader(open('test_in.txt'))
cities = defaultdict(default_factory)
for row in reader:
    headers = [r for r in row.keys()]
    headers.remove('CITY')
    for i in headers:
        amount = int(row[i])
        cities[row["CITY"]][0] += amount
        max = cities[row["CITY"]][1]
        cities[row["CITY"]][1] = amount if max is None else amount if amount > max else max
        min = cities[row["CITY"]][2]
        cities[row["CITY"]][2] = amount if min is None else amount if amount < min else min
        cities[row["CITY"]][3] += 1


for city in cities:
    cities[city][3] = cities[city][0]/cities[city][3] # calculate mean

with open('test_out.txt', 'wb') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter="\t")
    writer.writerow(["CITY", "AMOUNT", "AMOUNT2", "AMOUNTn ,"max", "min", "mean"])
    writer.writerows([city] + cities[city] for city in cities)
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `itertools.groupby`.

```
import StringIO
import csv
import itertools

data = """CITY,AMOUNT,AMOUNT2,AMOUNTn
London,20,21,22
Tokyo,45,46,47
London,55,56,57
New York,25,26,27"""

# I use StringIO to create a file like object for demo purposes
f = StringIO.StringIO(data) 
fieldnames = f.readline().strip().split(',')
key = lambda x: x[0] # the first column will be a grouping key
# rows must be sorted by city before passing to itertools.groupby
rows_sorted = sorted(csv.reader(f), key=key)
outfile = StringIO.StringIO('')
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
writer.writeheader()
for city, rows in itertools.groupby(rows_sorted, key=key):
    # remove city column for aggregation, convert to ints
    rows = [[int(x) for x in row[1:]] for row in rows] 
    agg = [sum(column) for column in zip(*rows)]
    writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, [city] + agg)))

print outfile.getvalue()

# CITY,AMOUNT,AMOUNT2,AMOUNTn
# London,75,77,79
# New York,25,26,27
# Tokyo,45,46,47
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and I'm unfortunately not very familiar with itertools.  Would it possible to include basic summary stats on each column, such as mean, max and min values?

Comment: You can change the statistic at the agg line. Replace `sum` with `max`, `min`, or your mean function.

Comment: That methods looks pretty straightforward, thanks for pointing that out.  Do you have any idea why my output file is blank when I make the following change?  `outfile = open('C:/path/to/file.txt' 'wb')`

Comment: Did you forget to close it at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

data = '''CITY,AMOUNT,AMOUNT2,AMOUNTn
London,20,21,22
Tokyo,45,46,47
London,55,56,57,99
New York,25,26,27'''

file_ = StringIO(data)

reader = csv.reader(file_)
headers = next(reader)

rows = {}

def add(col1, col2):
    l = len(col1)
    for i, n in enumerate(col2):
        if i >= l:
            col1.extend(col2[i:])
            break
        col1[i] += n
    return col1

for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    nums = map(int, row[1:])
    if key in rows:
        rows[key] = add(rows[key], nums)
    else:
        rows[key] = map(int, nums)
```