# Parsing a csv file and aggregate values in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm looking to parse a csv file and aggregate 2 columns.

Data in csv file:

```
'IP Address', Severity
10.0.0.1, High
10.0.0.1, High
10.0.0.1, Low
10.0.0.1, Medium
10.0.0.2, Medium
10.0.0.2, High
10.0.0.2, Low
10.0.0.3, Medium
10.0.0.3, High
10.0.0.3, Medium
```

I'm looking to obtain output along the lines of:

```
'IP Address', Severity
10.0.0.1, High:2, Medium:1, Low:1
10.0.0.2, High:1, Medium:1, Low:1
10.0.0.3, High:1, Medium:2, Low:0
```

or (ideally)

```
'IP Address', High, Medium, Low
10.0.0.1, 2, 1, 1
10.0.0.2, 1, 1, 1
10.0.0.3, 1, 2, 0
```

The closest I have come is here: 
[Parse CSV file and aggregate the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800111/parse-csv-file-and-aggregate-the-values)

I can't seem to aggregate on string (Severity) variable.

How can output this data?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to be looking at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which will do a lot of this stuff very conveniently for you... You should be able to find very similar questions if you browse through the pandas tag. Otherwise, search for python grouping csv data...

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv 
from collections import defaultdict

with open('text.txt') as f, open('ofile.csv','w+') as g:
    reader,writer = csv.reader(f), csv.writer(g)
    results = defaultdict(list)
    next(reader) #skip header line
    for ip,severity in reader:
        results[ip].append(severity)
    writer.writerow(["'IP Adress'"," High"," Medium"," Low"]) #Write headers
    for ip,severities in sorted(results.iteritems()):
        writer.writerow([ip]+[severities.count(t) for t in [" High"," Medium"," Low"]])
```

Produces:

```
'IP Adress', High, Medium, Low
10.0.0.1,2,1,1
10.0.0.2,1,1,1
10.0.0.3,1,2,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, ag.py:

```
import collections
import csv
import sys

output = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    reader.next() # Skip header line
    for ip,level in reader:
        level = level.strip() # Remove surrounding spaces
        output[ip][level] += 1

print "'IP Address',High,Medium,Low"
for ip, count in output.items():
    print '{0},{1[High]},{1[Medium]},{1[Low]}'.format(ip, count)
```

To run the solution, issue the following command:

```
python ag.py data.csv
```

#### Discussion

- `output` is a dictionary whose keys are the IP, and values are `collections.Counter` objects.
- Each counter object counts 'High', 'Medium', and 'Low' for a particular IP
- My solution prints to the stdout, you can modify it to print to file