# d3.js CSV data aggregation

Tags: d3.js

I want to aggregate data that I read in as CSV. I tried d3.nest and it works but it is not what I am looking for since it converts the data into a JSON structure. The important thing for me is to keep the CSV interface intact so that my reusable charts work whether I use raw or aggregated CSV data. I think it would be great if one could use map reduce for aggregation.

for example convert this:

```
a,b,c
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,1
2,1,1
2,2,1
2,3,1
2,4,1
3,1,1
3,2,1
3,3,1
3,4,1
3,5,1
3,6,1
4,1,1
4,2,1
```

into this:

```
a,d
1,4
2,4
3,6
4,2
```

I tried out the solution proposed by Adam Pearce but it did not work since it aggregates data into string format. Based on Adams idea I modified the code a bit. I used nest for the aggregation and map to get the data structure I wanted. Here is what I came up in the end:

```
    var aggregated = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
            var ts;
            var key = new Date(parseInt(d.ms_since_epoch));
            key.setMinutes(0);
            key.setSeconds(0);
            key.setMilliseconds(0);
            return key.getTime();
        })
        .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
        .entries(data)
        .map(function(d) { return {'ms_since_epoch': d.key, 'requests_hour': d.values}; })
```

Comment: the idea behind D3.js is to manipulate the way that data is displayed/visualized. If you want/need to manipulate the data itself, there is some leeway with D3.js, but that's not the intention behind it. `d3.nest` is likely what you need. The conversion only affects the data you feed to D3.js, not the _source_ of the data itself.

Comment: Also, I noticed you have the `python` tag in your profile. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800111/parse-csv-file-and-aggregate-the-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea - you might want to decouple how you're reading the data from how you're displaying - but creating a CSV from d3.nest isn't too complicated;

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){ return d.a; })
  .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
  .entries(data)
  .map(function(d){ return d.key + ',' + d.values; })
  .join("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library.

You can read your data from CSV files (as well as from XLSX file):

```
alasql('SELECT a, COUNT(*) AS d FROM CSV("mydata.csv",{headers:true}) GROUP BY a',
    [],function(data){
    // use data in d3.
});
```

Or if you already have data loaded in memory, you can use sync version of alasql():

```
var csvData = [{a:1,b:1,c:1},{a:1,b:2,c:1},{a:1,b:3,c:1}];

var data = alasql('SELECT a, COUNT(*) AS d FROM ? GROUP BY a',[csvData]);
```

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/gpwvbtng/1/) at jfFiddle.